# Optimize spring application context load time by removing ConfigurationPostProcessor

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

This question is directed to people who are familiar/interested in Spring's internals. Pivotal guys- I hope you come across this.

My application uses spring DI. We mix annotation based beans like @Service and @component with plain old xml based beans.

At some point the load times of the application context have become unbearable (30-90 sec) depending on developer machine.

I ran a profiler on on the loading of the application context and found an interesting thing:

it spends a large portion of the time inside `org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor`, specifically in processConfigBeanDefinitions.

It iterates over a list of candidates, checking whether the are annotated with "@Bean" or "@Configuration" or any of their buddies.

I am willing to give up on annotation based configuration based on the observation that it takes so much time.

I found a way to remove this post processor by implementing a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor and removing org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor. Indeed it sped up the load time significantly.

so the question is:

1. is this safe? or is it a dangerous hack?
2. it seems that this class does not respect the package name configured in the  section- it iterates over too many candidates. Why is that?
3. Other suggestions?

Comment: You can do everything by manual configuration, just add the approparate `BeanPostProcessor` and `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` instances. Drawback is that you will loose component-scanning. Also updating to a more recent version of spring might also help as there are several performance improvements in newer versions.

Comment: @M.Deinum, updated the question.

Comment: You loose part of the way of configuring your application yuo cannot use `@Configuration`, `@Bean` and `@PropertySource` anymore as that is all handled by that class. Also I don't get your second question/option, why should it iterate over too manu candidates? It iterates over ALL the beans in the context and then decided if it is a lite or full configuration class.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I would expect it to iterate only the classes that are specified inside the <component-scan> section. After all- the beans that are defined in XML are already handled- there is no need to iterate over them as well. The whole point of the post processor is to find the 'extra' beans that are defined with annotations and add them to the context, as documentation specifies, it is supposed to look for them in the packages of <component-scan>, not the entire class path.

Comment: There is no way to only do that. You could also specify a `@Configuration` class as a bean in XML. The post processor still needs to check those, the same applies for detecting `@Bean` methods on other class. It does a little more and due to the fact that you can mix and match configuration styles it is simply not possible to do. Also there is nothing in the documentation that says it only processes beans that are scanned, it says it processes beans with certain annotations in the context. Hence it iterates over all the beans in the context to detect the annotations.

Comment: @M.Deinum, are you saying that the intention is to support mix mode configuration *inside* the bean itself? (where the configuration of the a single bean is spread between XML and code. This seems like a bad idea to me though). When I originally thought about 'mixed' I though of some beans in xml and other in code, not same bean part in xml and part in code. This is a bit beside the point but I think it is a bad idea to mix at this level. (not to mention that it penalizes loading time)

Comment: No mixing xml configuration and java config. You cannot have a bean partially in xml and java that isn't going to work. But the initial support with java configuraiton was adding a `@Configuration` annotated bean in xml. Later the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` was added. However you still can have beans in xml with a `@Bean` annotated method (or contributing a `@PropertySource`) regardless the source (xml, javaconfig, or a properties file (yes you can have an application context setup from property files) it should work.

Comment: @M.Deinumbut but why?! isn't it supposed to be either-or? what is the point of defining a bean in Xml *and* annotating the same bean with 'Bean' or 'Service' etc? Also, I'll very much appreciate if you shed some light on the underlying design (or direct me to some links).

Comment: Well you have an application already using xml, now you want to use a new library that is using java config. Are you going to rewrite your whole application to use java config? The `ConfigurationClassPostProcessor` is a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` and that operates on `BeanDefinition`s. And where those come from it doesn't matter nor does it care. It should be the same regardless the source. Else you would have a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` ignoring part of your beans, that would be quite suprising...

Comment: @M.Deinum I think I am having trouble explaining myself :-)
I'll try to rephrase. I understand that from the perspective of the bean factory it doesn't matter where did the bean come from. What I don't understand is why Xml beans are still considered candidates in the ConfigurationClassPostProcessor. After all- they whole point is that they are *not* configuration beans.

In other words: suppose that inside ConfigurationPostProcessor I'd treat only beans that came from <component-scan> as configuration candidates, what would brake?

Comment: The `ConfigurationClassPostProcessor` not only processes configuraiton classes... I suggest a read on the documentation between lite and full configuration classes. Regardless you can still have a class in xml which is a `@Confguration` class (a full configuration class) or a simple bean with a `@Bean` annotated method (for a factory method). If only things picked up from `@Configuration` classes or component scanning would be used that would be suprsing to users or force libraries to fully switch at once to java config.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122658/discussion-between-vitaliy-and-m-deinum).

Comment: @M.Deinum, left a message for you in a chat room. let me know if you prefer here. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122658/discussion-between-vitaliy-and-m-deinum

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for the patience and detailed explanation
Are you somehow affiliated with Spring team?
Regarding your last comment, I am not sure I agree (perhaps I am missing something). If ConfigPostProcessor took only stuff from <com-scan>, it would not mean that I could not use xml based. It is not a problem to load both, this is exactly what happens- by the time the code reaches the post processor, all bean definitions are loaded, now all that's left is to understand which ones are Bean/Service/... and that can be done only on the ones specified in com-scan. What am I missing?

Comment: No it cannot be only on the ones in the component-scan as you can still register beans in xml which are annotated wiht some `@Component` annotation. Or which just have a `@Bean` annotated method but are themselves not `@Component` annoated. Basically every bean is a component and is in that regard a possible candidate for a lite bean configuration ... I'm not affiliated but I once upon a time worked for Interface21/SpringSource and have been doing Spring before it was even Spring so I know  little about the internals :) ).

Comment: @M.Deinum, you were very helpful. Please answer based on our correspondence and I will accept it.